# How to parse an XML file and count it into an array and display it in a tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I have an application in which I am using NSXMLParser to parse the XML `file.xml`. Parsing is done to read a weather API and display values in custom cell of tableview. My problem is values are not added to the array.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <xml_api_reply version="1">
  - <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
    - <forecast_information>
        <city data="" /> 
        <postal_code data="" /> 
        <latitude_e6 data="50500000" /> 
        <longitude_e6 data="30500000" /> 
        <forecast_date data="2011-07-07" /> 
        <current_date_time data="2011-07-07 04:00:00 +0000" /> 
        <unit_system data="US" /> 
     </forecast_information>
   </weather>
<xml_api_reply>
```

I have fetched the values of the element city and current_date_time of forecast_information.

This is my parser class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class journeyxmlAppDelegate, forecast_information;


@interface XMLParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate> 
{
    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;

    journeyxmlAppDelegate *appDelegate;

    forecast_information *f;

}



-(XMLParser*) initXMLParser;

@end
```

This is parser .m file:

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "journeyxmlAppDelegate.h"
#import "forecast_information.h"

@implementation XMLParser

-(XMLParser *)initXMLParser
{
    [super init];

    appDelegate = (journeyxmlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    return self;
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"weather"]) {
        //Initialize the array.
        appDelegate = (journeyxmlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        appDelegate.xmlapireply = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"forecast_information"]) {

        f = [[forecast_information alloc] init];

        //Extract the attribute here.
        f.city = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"];
        f.postal_code = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
        f.latitude_e6 = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
        f.longitude_e6 = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
        f.forecast_date = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
        f.current_date_time = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];
        f.unit_system = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"];

        NSLog(@"%@Reading id value", f.city);
        NSLog(@"%@Reading id value", f.postal_code);
        NSLog(@"%@Reading id value", f.latitude_e6);
        NSLog(@"%@Reading id value", f.longitude_e6);
        NSLog(@"%@Reading id value", f.forecast_date);
        NSLog(@"%@Reading id value", f.current_date_time);
        NSLog(@"%@Reading id value", f.unit_system);
    }



    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"weather"])
        return;

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"forecast_information"]) {
        [appDelegate.xmlapireply addObject:f];

        [f release];
        f = nil;
    }
    else {


    [f setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
    }

}


- (void) dealloc {

    [f release];
    [currentElementValue release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

This is my element forecast information class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface forecast_information : NSObject 
{
    NSString *city;
    NSString *postal_code;
    NSString *latitude_e6; 
    NSString *longitude_e6; 
    NSString *forecast_date;  
    NSString *current_date_time;  
    NSString *unit_system; 
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *postal_code;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *latitude_e6;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *longitude_e6; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *forecast_date;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *current_date_time;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *unit_system; 

@end
```

This is .m file

```
#import "forecast_information.h"


@implementation forecast_information
@synthesize city;
@synthesize postal_code;
@synthesize latitude_e6;
@synthesize longitude_e6;
@synthesize forecast_date;
@synthesize current_date_time;
@synthesize unit_system;


- (void) dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
    [city release];
    [postal_code release];
    [latitude_e6 release];
    [longitude_e6 release];
    [forecast_date release];
    [current_date_time release];
    [unit_system release];

}

@end
```

This is my controller class where I am displaying values in tableview.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class journeyxmlAppDelegate;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController
{
    journeyxmlAppDelegate *appDelegate;

}

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "journeyxmlAppDelegate.h"
#import "forecast_information.h"
#import "current_conditions.h"
#import "forecast_conditions.h"
#import "TWeatherCell.h"

@implementation RootViewController


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    appDelegate = (journeyxmlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [appDelegate.xmlapireply count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TWeatherCell *cell =(TWeatherCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[TWeatherCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    forecast_information *f = [appDelegate.xmlapireply objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Value of f:%@",f);
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.reportdate.text = f.city;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.conditionname.text = f.postal_code;
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.twotemp.text = f.current_date_time;
            cell.humidity.text = f.unit_system;
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is no value is displayed in my tableview cell. What may be the problem?

Comment: You should post the code you've tried and someone can help you fix it.

Comment: Hi @Firoze Lafeer i have edited my question by posting code in it .Please check

Comment: Are you getting no elements in your final array **appDelegate.xmlapireply**?

Comment: Does the array have the correct number of forecast_information objects, but the properties for each forecast_information object are empty strings? Or is the array itself empty?

Comment: @Firoze Lafeer my array is counting only 1 object which is the tag forecast information.Inside tags of forecast information are not counted.What may be the problem

Comment: Your NSLog values printing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might forget to allocate the array.

### Edit

If this is the xml, then you would probably get only one count.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This will get executed only once, because your array count is 1.

```
        case 1:
            cell.conditionname.text = f.postal_code;
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.twotemp.text = f.current_date_time;
            cell.humidity.text = f.unit_system;
            break;
```

This won't get executed, only it executes the case 0. Understand the use of cellForRowAtIndexPath clearly.

Comment: i have allocated the array.i have edited the question by posting code in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;` delegate method and accumulate the characters of the strings into an NSMutableString* instance variable that is allocated in init or begin parse. This instance variable will contain the value for each tag at the `endTag...` delegate method.

Additionally, you will probably want to implement the `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;` delegate method so that it can empty out the `NSMutableString` instance variable for the current (new) tag.

see "Event-Driven XML Programming Guide" [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI) Listing 3 where it refers to "currentStringValue"